# Hangout app XMLHttpRequest cannot load error when trying to call a .php file to get data

Tags: mysql, xmlhttprequest, google-hangouts

I am trying to talk to mysql from my Google Hangout app and the test code works fine from an HTML page, but gets blocked when I run it in the app .XML wrapper in a hangout.

There I get this in the console (I had to replace the URLs due to me being new here) :

<<<<<>>>>>

XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXXXXX MY file URL XXXXX. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https XXXXXX GOOGLE USER CONTENT XXXXX' is therefore not allowed access. ifr?url=app%3A%2F%2F609528936436%2Fhangout&container=hangout&view=default&lang=all&country=ALL&debu…:1
GET XXXXXX MY file URL again only with https XXXXX net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ifr?url=app%3A%2F%2F609528936436%2Fhangout&container=hangout&view=default&lang=all&country=ALL&debu…:1199
XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXXXXX MY file URL XXXXX. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https XXXXXX GOOGLE USER CONTENT XXXXX' is therefore not allowed access. ifr?url=app%3A%2F%2F609528936436%2Fhangout&container=hangout&view=default&lang=all&country=ALL&debu…:1

<<<<<>>>>>

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER Thanks to Gerwin Sturm:

Your problem seems to be that with the Hangout App running inside of an iframe hosted on Google servers your server refuses to send content to this different domain.

Two possible solution:
1) Set the headers on your server to allow cross-origin request. In your php script you should be able to do this by calling

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

2) Use https://hangoutiframer.appspot.com, which allows you to run the hangout app on your own server, preventing CORS problems that way.﻿

Comment: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); in the PHP file worked! Thank you Gerwin!